# Check open status of Microsoft Excel from MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, xls, xlsx

I open a file from MATLAB with this code :

```
winopen('myFile.xlsx')
```

I want MATLAB delete this file after the user closes this file in Microsoft Excel. What should I do?

Comment: checking for ~*.xlsx?

Comment: I only want know when user will close that specific file `('myFile.xlsx')` to remove the file after that. If the file is open and I want delete it, I have a permission error in MATLAB.

Comment: Excel will create a ~*.xlsx file when opening *.xlsx, and delete it after successfuly closing it. Let Matlab watch for that temporary file (which essentially is a lock). Alternatively, you can make a C++ program that finds window with title "Excel ... *.xlsx". That involves Windows API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I pause my program until a specific file will delete? (~*.xlsx file)

Comment: No need (no way) to pause the script. Instead, frequently check for the file (say every 500 ms), in a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do this :

```
    while exist([File_Path '~$File_name'], 'file')==2       
    end
    delete([File_Path 'File_name']);
```

thank you @Yvon for helping and your comments.

Answer (score 1):

To check if an executable is running (even in background), use Window's "tasklist.exe"

To know if Excel is running from Matlab, try

```
ExeName = 'EXCEL.EXE';
[~,msg] = system(['tasklist /fi "ImageName eq ' ExeName '"']);
IsOpen  = ~isempty(strfind(msg,upper(ExeName)));
```

IsOpen is a boolean vale that gives true if Excel is opened. If you use it in a while loop, or in a timer function, checking if the file is open or not.

I think is simpler just to try to delete the file. If it is in use, Matlab will not allow you to delete it.